# Managed Package- Static Resource Cache Control

Tags: managed-package, static-resources

I know how 'Cache Control' setting on static resource works. What I don't know if there is any impact on managed package future releases.

Does the 'Cache Control' setting on Static Resource have any impact on the future releases of a managed package?

Will I be able to delete the static resources from future releases of my managed package regardless of the 'Cache Control' setting?

Comment: That behavior would be mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm), but it seems the documentation doesn't say. You might try contacting support.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the link. I did came across with that link which does not say anything about impact on packaging. I got an answer from support. please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer from support**

Yes, you can delete static resources from future releases of a managed package regardless of the "Cache Control" setting. The "Cache Control" setting primarily affects how browsers and proxy servers cache the static resources once they are accessed by users, but it doesn't prevent you from removing those resources from future releases.

It's important to note that when you remove a static resource from a managed package in a new version, users who upgrade to that version will no longer have access to that resource. If your application or package relies on a specific static resource, you should ensure that any necessary replacements or updates are provided in the new version to avoid breaking functionality.